# Activate the tab of the location hash

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, anchor

I have a structure of tabs with 3 levels:

```
<!-- Nav tabs - First level -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>    
<!-- Tab panes - First level -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">       
    <p>Home content.</p>      
    <!-- Nav tabs - Second level -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile 2</a></li>
    </ul>    
    <!-- Tab panes - Second level -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home2">          
      <p>Home 2 content.</p>              
      <!-- Nav tabs - Third level -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home3-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile3-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile 3-1</a></li> 
    </ul>    
    <!-- Tab panes - Third level -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home3-1"><p>Home 3-1 content.</p></div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile3-1"><p>Profile 3-1 content.</p></div>
    </div>          
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile2">
      <p>Profile 2 content.</p>         
      <!-- Nav tabs - Third level -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home3-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile3-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile 3-2</a></li> 
    </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes - Third level -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home3-2"><p>Home 3-2 content.</p></div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile3-2"><p>Profile 3-2 content.</p></div>
    </div>           
      </div>
    </div>         
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile content.</div>
</div>
```

This code could be checked here: (http://jsfiddle.net/bvta2/3/).

When you access the link http://fiddle.jshell.net/bvta2/3/show/#profile3-1, the Profile 3-1 tab appears active. However, when accessing http://fiddle.jshell.net/bvta2/3/show/#home3-2, for example, the Home 3-2 tab is not active.

How can I solve this using jQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `#home3-2` is nested within a tab that is hidden.

Another way to look at this is what would happen for the following code?:

```
<div> 1
    <div style="display:none"> 2
        <div style="display:block"> 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even though you have made the bottom div visible, it will still be hidden by its parent.

When loading the page, you'll have to traverse the dom for any hidden parent tabs and call `show` on them as well.

```
if (location.hash) {
    $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
    // code to also show parent tabs
}
```

You could do that like this:

```
//get the hashed element and find all of it's parent tabs that aren't active
$(location.hash).parents('.tab-pane:not(.active)').each(function() {
    //each pane should have an id - find it's anchor target and call show
    $('a[href=#' + this.id + ']').tab('show');
});
```

Demo in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/bvta2/11/show/#home3-2

Comment: Thanks, @KyleMit. Your code worked like a charm. I have a problem with multiple tabs in a real project. I will send you a e-mail. Hugs!