# How to return to a specific tab in a view using MVC 5 Bootstrap tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an MVC 5 web app with Bootstrap tabs.  The tabs contain content that links to other pages.  When the user returns to the original page, I want them to return to the same tab they were originally on.

For example:  A user is on page "A", tab 3, and clicks a link that takes them to page "B".  When they finish with page B, I want to return the user to page A, tab 3.

I've tried specifying the fragment in the ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "home", null, null, "myGroups", null, null)
```

but that only partial works.  It will take me back to the correct page, but it always lands on the first tab.

How do I return to the page AND select the correct tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just navigate to the hash of a tab since bootstrap has some more settings like `.active` class to apply.

Instead, run some javascript on every page load to look for a fragment and then react appropriately.

Like this from [Activate the tab of the location hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24788653/1366033):

```js
if (location.hash) {
    $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
}
```