# How to make tabs Linkable in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using Bootstrap in my rails application and i want to make tabs linkable with this form  `http://example.com/?tab=tab-one` and `http://example.com/?tab=tab-two` so I'm wondering how can I achieve this

My tabs is something like this

```
  <div class="optionset-menu bxsbdbdr">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs setcustom-tab" role="tablist">
      <a href="#summary" aria-controls="summary" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><li role="presentation" class="active hav-bordbot">Basic Infos</li></a>
      <a href="#languages-time" aria-controls="anguages-time" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><li role="presentation" class="hav-bordbot">Language & Time zone</li></a>
      <a href="#basic" aria-controls="basic" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><li role="presentation" class="havnt-bordbot">Change password</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: check this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: I'm able to generate tabs using bootstrap, but I'm wondering how can i make tabs linkable with this from http://example.com/?tab=tab-two

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activate the tab of the location hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786125/activate-the-tab-of-the-location-hash)

Answer (score 3):

You can see my answer to [Activate the tab of the location hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24788653/1366033) for more info.

If you want to navigate to the selected URL when the page loads, you'll need to add javascript on page load to gather the necessary information from the URL and then use that to open the appropriate panel.

Here's an example using the hash value of the tab:

```js
$(function() {

    // jump to tab if it exists 
    if (location.hash) {
        $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    }

    // add tab hash to url to persist state
    $(document.body).on("shown.bs.tab", function(e){
      location.hash = e.target.hash;
    });

});
```

If the tab had an ID of `tab-two`, you could open it with the url `http://example.com/#tab-two`

#### [Here's a demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wfaHs8wOzZPkBK7Gn7WO)

Open the window or [run it directly here](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/wfaHs8wOzZPkBK7Gn7WO)

Comment: @avinodra, the plunker has working code that is able to do what you're asking.  If you want people to debug your code, you should provide a complete sample that reproduces the issue online.  It looks like you only posted half of the HTML necessary.  Can you try either, incorporating the changes from the working plunk, or forking it and adding your code to your own version so we can see what you can see happening.

Comment: Even this Plunker code don't seem to be a working code and i have post only the half of my code because this half that matter

Comment: @avinodra, all the code matters when you're trying to let someone else see your problem.  Otherwise I would have to guess at what that code is at worst, and have to retype it all manually at best.  For things pertaining to the window location, jsFiddle and stack snippets usually won't cut it because they embed the result page as an IFrame.  Try opening the plunk as it's own window or going to this address: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/wfaHs8wOzZPkBK7Gn7WO